# convertPoint:toView: Doesn't seem to be working

Tags: iphone, coordinates

I have a TableView with custom TableCellViews that has UILabels and UIButtons on it.
when one of the buttons is taped I want to show a "tooltip" describing the text of the button.

Most everything is working except for when I try to convert the center coordinates of the UIButton to the coordinates of the rootView which is a UIView.

Here is the code:

```
- (void) fancyLabelButtonPressed: (UIButton *) button {
  CGPoint btnPoint = button.center;   // x=200.5 y=27.5
  CGPoint rootViewPoint = [button convertPoint:btnPoint toView:rootView];
  // rootViewPoint -> x=390.5 y=197.5
  CGPoint pointToUse = CGPointMake(btnPoint.x +20, rootViewPoint.y - 23); // Hack to get it close
}
```

How can `rootViewPoint.x=390.5` when I'm in portrait view?!!?  By using the x from the button and the y from the rootViewPoint I get close to what it should be but it is just a hack.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? or is there a better way?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is because you are converting the point from the wrong view. The `center` property is actually in the coordinate system of the button's superview, whatever that is, so when you convert it to your rootView, you must convert it from there. So:

```
rootViewPoint = [[button superview] convertPoint:btnPoint toView:rootView];
```

That should give you what you are looking for.